# How to minimize matrix function in MathCAD?

Tags: matrices, optimization, math-software

I need to minimize my function `Trr(Rr)`, where `Rr` is matrix with given constraints, `Trr` returns sum of its elements

Here's what I did:

[image]

MathCAD says

> Variable is not determined

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just wrote one of conditions twice.

[image]